Themed spacing that is calculated from other themed spacings in Tailwind CSS
My page layout (a fixed navbar with a relative footer, with a growing content section in between) requires me to make some height-calculations based on the heights of other elements.
To make it a little more clear what's happening here in my project, I want to use themed spacings for these elements.
i.e. i have the navigation bar itself, a wavey SVG acting as a border to the bottom of the navbar, and a footer.
spacing: {
    nav: '6rem',
    wave: '4rem',
    footer: '6rem'
}

it'd be nice if I could do something like min-h-[calc(100dvh-nav-wave-footer] to set the height of the content wrapper, or set a mt-[calc(nav+wave)].
Right now I see two ways of accomplishing this, but they both seem kind of iffy.
I could add a  navwave to the themed spacings section equal to the 'magic' number 10rem. Obviously that gets annoying when you're trying to update the height of one of these elements and forgot to alter the navwave element.
or, I could do it like so: mt-[calc(theme('spacing.nav')+theme('spacing.wave'))] which is quite a mouthful, growing the line. It is considerably longer than any other directives I'm normally using, and thus quite distracting to work with.
So, instead of having such calculations directly in my HTML, I wanted to add a custom navwave spacing to my theme config that does that calculation automatically.
spacing: {
   nav: '6rem',
   wave: '4rem',
   navwave: "calc(theme('spacing.nav')+theme('spacing.wave'))"
}

...That's when I stumbled upon the problem I'm writing this post for. For some reason, only one of the theme directives gets converted if I do it that way, and it causes the browser to say that it's an invalid property. Refer to these screenshots for more information:


Did I do something wrong? Or is what I'm doing not supported by Tailwind (yet)?

You could have the spacings as a variable in the configuration:
const mySpacings = {
   nav: '6rem',
   wave: '4rem',
};

// …

spacing: 
   ...mySpacings,
   navwave: `calc(${mySpacings.nav} + ${mySpacings.wave})`,
}



const mySpacings = {
  nav: '6rem',
  wave: '4rem',
};

tailwind.config = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      spacing: {
         ...mySpacings,
         navwave: `calc(${mySpacings.nav} + ${mySpacings.wave})`,
      }
    },
  },
};
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.3"></script>

<div class="mt-navwave h-10 bg-red-500"></div>



This stops the magic numbers since we are now using the named references.

As an aside, your solution almost works too, you'd need to add spaces around the + operand for Tailwind (and the browser) to interpret it correctly:
navwave: "calc(theme('spacing.nav') + theme('spacing.wave'))"



tailwind.config = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      spacing: {
         nav: '6rem',
         wave: '4rem',
         navwave: "calc(theme('spacing.nav') + theme('spacing.wave'))"
      }
    },
  },
};
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.3"></script>

<div class="mt-navwave h-10 bg-red-500"></div>




That is wild, I never internalized that! I read up more on it here
